# Deleting a certain folder using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-xp

I have a folder that I keep all my downloads in for the month. I would like to be able to hit a key combination and have all the downloads for that month deleted. Would that be at all possible? The key combination can be anything. Here's where I keep all my downloads if needed.

```
C:\Program Files\Downloads\August (2010)\
```

If possible, the key combination would delete everything in the folder, but still leave the folder there. If that's not possible, then deleting the folder also be ok.

Comment: !ProgrammingRelated ?? MoveTo.SuperUser; // http://superuser.com

Comment: You should post your question on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) (and delete it here).

Comment: @wuputah - Instead of deleting, it's ok to wait until it's closed.  I voted to close, and we just need to wait for 4 more votes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, although haven't done something like that before, I'd suggest you try to set up a script in [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), then assign it to a keyboard shortcut, or to a time event when the folder will be deleted. [FileRemoveDir](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRemoveDir.htm) function could prove to be useful, if you wish to remove the folder as well. There is an example of its usage at the bottom.

Also, the folder could be deleted via a simple batch script, but then assigning a shortcut could prove to be just a little bit more difficult than with this approach.

Comment: +1 for [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).